# Recursive program reaches return statement, but jumps back to call in method

Tags: java, recursion

When I run this program through eclipse's debugger, in the method `randomRecursion`, once i is less than `0`, it skips to the return, but then jumps back up to the `randomRecursion` call. Why is this?

```
public class RecursiveExample {

    public static double randomRecursion(double a, double b, int i) {
        while (i > 0) { 
            b = ((1 / a) - a) * b;
            i = i - 1;
            randomRecursion(a, b, i);
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(randomRecursion(.5, .5, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are calling your method 5 time inside your loop. What exactly are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the recursive method doesn't terminate your method - you missed the `return` there. Once you've done that, as @pjs mentioned in the comments, you really have no need for a `while` loop - you just need a simple conditional statement:

```
public static double randomRecursion(double a, double b, int i) {
    if (i > 0) { 
        b = ((1 / a) - a) * b;
        i = i - 1;
        // return was missing here
        return RandomRecursion(a, b, i);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Without that return there, what was happening with my code?

Comment: @JohnRecursive without the `return` statement you execute the recursive function, ignore its output, and just go on with the `while` loop.

Comment: Oh! I'm an idiot, I get it now. I wasn't doing anything with the output of my function.

Comment: @JohnRecursive yup, exactly

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  If you put a `return` where you're suggesting, there's no point in having a loop -- it should become a conditional, because you'll only go through it once.  I agree that something needs to be done with the recursive call's return value, though.